# Generating a new SITE_KEY

Tags: civicrm.settings.php

One of my clients' webhosts posted the SITE_KEY of their site on a publicly accessible webpage.  How do I generate a new SITE_KEY with the same random process that generated the original?

Comment: Next: [What will happen when I change the SITE_KEY?](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/what-are-the-implications-of-changing-the-site-key)

Answer (score 4):

Any source of unknown data should be fine - I'd use a command like this just because it's quicker:

```
head -n 1000 /dev/urandom | md5sum
```

Comment: NB: "it's quicker" isn't great criteria for cryptographic RNG - but I do think this will give you a very hard to predict key

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement to generate the SITE_KEY in the same way. (In fact, the algorithm changed in v4.6.3.) Rather, follow these requirements:

- Stick to alphanumerics
- Provide decent entropy (I think 90 bits would be decent, but there's no downside to going higher)

For some better ways to generate a SITE_KEY:

- On Debian/Ubuntu-based systems, run: `sudo apt-get install makepasswd && makepasswd  --chars=32` (~190 bits)
- Use [mkpasswd.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/blob/master/bin/mkpasswd.php) from [civicrm-buildkit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit), eg: `mkpasswd.php 32` (~190 bits)
- Do something closer to v4.6's algorithm: `php -r 'echo md5(rand() . mt_rand() . rand() . uniqid("", TRUE) . "www.example.org") . "\n";'` (~128 bits)

**Random Tip**: If you use an authenticated SMTP service for mail delivery and you change the SITE_KEY, then you may need to re-enter the SMTP password.