# What are the implications of changing the SITE_KEY?

Tags: security, civicrm.settings.php

See also [Generating a new SITE_KEY](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3246/generating-a-new-site-key)

If I change the SITE_KEY in civicrm.settings.php, what might stop working as a result?

Eg:

- Will checksums emailed to contacts last week still be valid?

(you're welcome to to edit question or comment to add to this)

Answer (score 5):

1. Change all cron jobs and scripts that use the site key for authentication
2. Reenter any passwords, specifically payment processors and mail/sms passwords
3. All prior checksums sent in the last 7 days (if that value has not been changed), will no longer work

A grep for SITE_KEY in the code base will uncover a few more things :)